# Ordinary n-uple Points and Resolution of Singularities on a Surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory

Let $X$ be an algebraic variety over some algebraically closed field $\Bbbk$ and let us assume $\dim(X)=2$, i.e. $X$ is an algebraic surface.

First, I would like to know the definition of an **ordinary $n$-uple singular point** on $X$, because in the Literature I know, it is only defined with respect to curves. Wolfram Mathworld has [a definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrdinaryDoublePoint.html), but $X$ does not always admit an embedding into $\mathbb{P}^3$, i.e. it is not necessarily defined by a single equation $f(x,y,z)$, so I am really not sure how this generalizes.

Second, I have been told that such singularities can be resolved by *"blowing up once"* - I would really like to know why that is, i.e. I am looking for a paper or textbook with this statement in it. If it is trivial to proove, of course, that request may be void.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A germ $(X, p)$ of isolated surface singularity is called an *ordinary n-tuple point* if
$$\hat{\mathcal{O}}_p=\mathbb{C}[[ x^n, x^{n-1}y, \ldots, xy^{n-1}, y^n]],$$
see for instance Miyaoka's paper [The maximal number of quotient singularities on surfaces with given numerical invariants](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01456083), Section 1.

Equivalently, this can be seen as:

1. the singularity type (at its vertex) of the cone $C_n$ over the rational normal curve of degree $n$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$. In particular the embedding dimension is $n+1$, so it cannot be realized as a isolated singularity in $\mathbb{P}^3$ unless $n=2$ (ordinary double point);
2. the cyclic quotient singularity $\frac{1}{n}(1,1)$, i.e. the quotient of $\mathbb{C}^2$ by the action of the group $\mathbf{Z}/n \mathbf{Z}$ given by $$\xi \cdot (x,\ y) \to (\xi x, \ \xi y),$$ where $\xi$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity. In particular it is a *rational* singularity.

   The fact that such singularities can be resolved by "blowing up once" is a standard computation. Or, if you prefer, just note that the blow up of the cone $C_n$ at its vertex is the Hirzebruch surface $\mathbf{F}_n$, which is smooth. This also shows that the minimal resolution of an ordinary $n$-tuple point is given by a smooth rational curve with self-intersection $-n$.

Comment: I think {\em ordinary $n$-tuple point} is also sometimes used for hypersurface singularities that are the cone over a smooth plane curve. For instance, the elliptic singularity $x^3+y^3+z^3=0$ is also called an ordinary triple point.


Comment: Dear Rita, this is also reasonable. Do you have any reference? Maybe Miyaoka meant that the ones mentioned in my answer are the only ordinary $n$-tuple points *among quotient singularities* 

Comment: @Francesco: in this Eprint http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/0010.5163, ordinary triple point is used in the sense I mentioned. The only case that satisfies both definitions is a singularity of type $A_1$, since the cone over $C_n$ is not a Gorenstein singularity for $n>2$. I think both definitions exist in the literature.

Comment: @Rita: Ok. Thank you very much for the link. 

Comment: What are $x$ and $y$? Does $\hat{\mathcal{O}}_P$ denote the completion of the local ring at $P$? 

Comment: Just two variables. Yes.

Comment: Note that the monomials $x^n$, $x^{n-1}y$, $\ldots$, $xy^{n-1}$, $y^n$ form a basis for the ring of invariants of the $\mathbf{Z}/n \mathbf{Z}$ action described in $2)$.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this really helped. For anyone else who might read this thread, I went looking for cyclic quotient singularities, because that definition appealed most to me. A very nice read (or so I found) was "Lectures on Resolution of Singularities" by Janus Kollar, Princeton University Press.

Comment: @rita the link in [your comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72492/ordinary-n-uple-points-and-resolution-of-singularities-on-a-surface/72504#comment184102_72504) is broken, here is a replacement: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0010163